# I am getting "PackageManagement\Install-Package : Access to the cloud file is denied" errors while installing Az module in power shell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-az-module

I am trying to install Az module on windows power shell by "Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Force -Allowclobber command". But i am getting below error.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Force -Allowclobber
PackageManagement\Install-Package : Access to the cloud file is denied
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PSModule.psm1:9711 char:34
+ ... talledPackages = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.Instal 
   lPackage
```

I searched and found some issue is with onedrive sync activated in my system. Can you please help me on this to install Az module in powershell.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason is PowerShell Gallery is blocked by the firewall. Anyway, try installing it using [MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps-msi?view=azps-6.0.0). It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install the latest release of the Az module and it worked Az 6.0.0.

Used the below link for reference.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases

Answer (score 0):

See if/where you have Az module installed already using this command

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

I found az installed in onedrive/documents/WindowsPowershell, and removed it by deleting the package manually.

Once deleted, I tried the install command again. That helped me.

To your question, I guess you'll have to check the PATH variable I guess, for you to avoid packages being installed in OneDrive(Happens probably when you run powershell with normal user rather than when run as admin).

Answer (score 0):

This is a security measure that decides which scripts can be run. The execution policy has four main configurations:

**Restricted** This configuration, which is the default, doesn’t allow you
to run scripts.

**AllSigned** This configuration allows you to run only scripts that have
been cryptographically signed by a trusted party

**RemoteSigned** This configuration allows you to run any script you
write, and any script you download as long as it’s been cryptographically signed by a trusted party.

**Unrestricted** This configuration allows you to run any scripts.

Solution:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force`

**NOTE:**

The solution above was dependent for my use case, yours may slightly be different from mine so apply extreme caution before using the solution provided.